# How do I get Google to show my site for variants of a keyword both with spaces and without spaces?

Tags: google-search, keywords

I have site where my target keyword phrase is of pattern **withoutspace** or **with space**. But Google search result doesn't show me result for **with space** and I get the result for **withoutspace**.

How can we handle this behavior to get the results for **with space** as well?

Note: **withoutspace** or **with space** are the patterns of keyword (phrase) I am using, they are not actual keyword for my website.

Comment: Why would you ever have keywords without spaces on the page? also, providing an example would go a long way.

Comment: I hate to sound like a broken record, but search is not about keywords. It is about whole language and understanding content. Any two terms concatinated without a space will not be recognized as a single term, but will be recognized as the two terms they are using nGram analysis. Since Google does not do search term matches, you cannot expect the baviour you are seeking. It will not happen.

Comment: @SimonHayter an example: mobileswop or mobile swop

Comment: @closetnoc I respect your angry reply... though I am aware that google treats those terms seperated by space as 2 different terms but I also read somewhere that if we have the occurance of those terms in sequence in content of page with relevant context.. but I cannot actually digest this explanation as I do have something like on my page content but still dont see results... but your comment has helped me to learn about nGram Analysis, thanks for that though

Comment: I was not being angry, just frustrated by all the SEO misinformation. Google will index what appears to be whole terms that do not reside within an ontology in an attempt to capture new terms it does not understand. However, it will not make matches against these terms except as a last step. So it will redily make search matches against language it understands. One exception is where branding signals come into play. Short of trying to establish a brand, using two terms as one is seriously going against the grain. It is an up hill climb I do not recommend. It goes against the nature of things.

Comment: BTW- I certainly did not mean to be offensive if I was. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc if i go by your explanations, then other competitive enterprise brands are also going wrong?? Because if I search ‘singtel mobile swop’ i find the result as singtel.com’s mobileswop program page... can you please help me understand this??

Comment: MobileSwop is Mobile Swop and vice versa, not because of the page content but because of people's searches and how they interact with the search engines, the same way Google understands misspellings on 'branding' non-dictionary words, it has nothing to do with 'page content' or meta descriptions or anything like that.

Comment: Simon is exactly right. Signals aside, none of that does a damned thing without brand searches. This is how Google knows for sure there is a new word out there... more than one site using it, it has semantic meaning even if not understood, and finally searches for that term that appears to match onsite context.

Comment: If you have a page for "ApplePhone" and a page for "Red Apple Phone Case", and one page is about the company Apple and another is about the actual fruit, Google should index both of those pages and show them in SERPs in relation to what people are searching for. Aside from that, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Help me conclude it @closetnoc SimonHayter , Michael,  if user search for MobileSwop results be displayed for it and if user searches for Mobile Swop then results are displayed for this combination only if there are other site’s available with this combination accordingly, they both needs to be there in content of page either as a title of page or somewhere in body in this sense... am I getting it right now?? Please suggest

Comment: Yes. The terms mist exist in content always. Here is one answer I wrote to a very different question where the answer is similar. It extensively explains some of what is 
going on. httpsebmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92372/google-has-a-hard-time-finding-organizations-official-page/92379#92379 If I find more, I will add a link here.

Comment: I am looking into the link provided, I will be highly Obliged for your help in form of artifacts for me to learn more about search facts..

Comment: @closetnoc or anyone,  After reading the details provided in link in above comment, is it ok if I use these 2 keyword phrases: "<somecarrier> mobile swop support" and "<somecarrier> mobileswop unlimted support" in the h1 tag as "Welcome to <somecarrier> MobileSwop Unlimited and MobileSwop chat support"???

Comment: Yes. You can do what you want. Just be warned that Google will split the terms and/or look for brand signals to see if it should consider it to be brand. If this is a brand name, then you want to send the right signals for that. Otherwise, matches gainst the two concatinated terms will not come as easily. Cheers!!